# How do I remove this type of screw/insert?

Tags: screws, furniture

How do I remove this type of screw? These are on the corners of a bed frame we are trying disassemble
[image: Inner insert removed]

[image: with inner screw]

Comment: It could be a driven in insert that is not designed to be removed. A hole is drilled and the insert has fins that help to hold it in the shoulder on the driven side keeps it from pulling through.

Comment: what's on the other side?

Comment: @David what happens if you turn counter-clockwise?

Comment: I wasn't able to pry it out without really forcing it so i stopped. There is nothing on the other side it doesn't go all the way through. I can turn the inner screw counter-clockwise and remove it and then it looks like the first picture.

Comment: @David it would have helped a lot if you said that the two pictures are not the same item viewed from both sides ... please delete the second picture because it does not add any useful information to the question ... in fact, it adds confusion

Comment: get a wide standard slot screwdriver that will fit snugly into the two recesses and turn the insert couter-clockwise

Comment: Looks like a fastener to hold a dowel at 90°, and is not meant to be removed, just given a 1/4 turn to release the dowel.

Comment: @jsotola I dont think I have a screwdriver wide enough for that (it's about an inch in diameter).

Comment: Can you explain or show us why you believe that insert needs to be removed? From what I can see on the photos it looks like it's intended as a permanent fixture which you screw something else into.

Comment: You're right the bed pulls apart once you remove the inner screw !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the OP only wanted to disassemble the bed, not actually remove the threaded insert. Removing the Phillips head screw in the second picture allowed the OP to accomplish his task.

*From a [comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214791/how-do-i-remove-this-type-of-screw-insert#comment398491_214791) by the OP:*

> You're right the bed pulls apart once you remove the inner screw !

<sup>Made CommunityWiki to highlight the answer the OP found himself and eliminate the "how did you solve this" question/answers from new users".</sup>